# Evaluation of definite integral without Trigonometric Substution

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> Finding value of $$\int^{\sqrt{1.5}}_{1}\int^{x\sqrt{x}}_{1}\frac{y}{\sqrt{2-x^2}}dydx$$ without Trigonometric substution

What i try

$$\int^{\sqrt{1.5}}_{1}\bigg(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2-x^2}}\int^{x\sqrt{x}}_{1}ydy\bigg)dx$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\int^{\sqrt{1.5}}_{1}\frac{x^3-1}{\sqrt{2-x^2}}dx$$

$$=\frac{1}{2}\int^{\sqrt{2}}_{1}\frac{x^3-1}{\sqrt{2-x^2}}dx+\frac{1}{2}\int^{\sqrt{1.5}}_{\sqrt{2}}\frac{x^3-1}{\sqrt{2-x^2}}dx$$

One way is to put $2-x^2=t^2$ and $xdx=-tdt$

Update:

$\displaystyle 
\frac{1}{2}\bigg[\int^{\sqrt{2}}_{1}\frac{x^3}{\sqrt{2-x^2}}dx+\int^{\sqrt{1.5}}_{\sqrt{2}}\frac{x^3}{\sqrt{2-x^2}}dx\bigg]- 
\frac{1}{2}\bigg[\int^{\sqrt{2}}_{1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2-x^2}}dx+\int^{\sqrt{1.5}}_{\sqrt{2}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2-x^2}}dx\bigg]$

After substution on $2-x^2=t^2$ getting

$\displaystyle \frac{1}{2}\bigg[1+0.5\bigg]-\frac{1}{2}[\int^{\sqrt{2}}_{1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2-x^2}}dx+\int^{\sqrt{1.5}}_{\sqrt{2}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2-x^2}}dx\bigg]$

How do i solve second integration.

Comment: You could split the terms, right? The one with x cubed separately, and the one with -1 separately. In the x cubed term, x^2 can be written using your t^2, and xdx can be written as tdt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Continue with

$$\begin{align}
& \int^{\sqrt{1.5}}_{1}\frac{x^3-1}{\sqrt{2-x^2}}dx\\
& =\int^{\sqrt{1.5}}_{1}\frac{x^3-2x+2x}{\sqrt{2-x^2}}dx
-\int^{\sqrt{1.5}}_{1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2-x^2}}dx \\
& =\int^{\sqrt{1.5}}_{1} \left(-x\sqrt{2-x^2}+\frac{2x}{\sqrt{2-x^2}}\right) dx 
-\int^{\sqrt{1.5}}_{1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2-x^2}}dx \\
& =\int^{\sqrt{1.5}}_{1} \left(\frac12\sqrt{2-x^2}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2-x^2}}\right) d(2-x^2) \\
&\>\>\>\>\>-\int^{\sqrt{1.5}}_{1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\left(\frac x{\sqrt2} \right) ^2}}d\left(\frac x{\sqrt2} \right)\\
& =\left( \frac13(2-x^2)^{3/2} -2\sqrt{2-x^2}\right)\bigg|_1^{\sqrt{1.5}} 
-\sin^{-1}\frac x{\sqrt2}\bigg|_1^{\sqrt{1.5}} \\
\end{align}$$

Comment: Thanks Quanto. But function is discontinuous at $x=\sqrt{2}.$

Comment: @jacky - note $\sqrt2 > \sqrt{1.5}$. The integrand is continuous within limits $x\in (1, \sqrt{1.5})$

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the point of splitting the integration range into the intervals $[1,\sqrt{2}]$ and $[\sqrt{2},\sqrt{1.5}]$. That introduces improper integrals (which happen to be convergent), and doesn't lead to any simplification. Just evaluate
$$\int_1^{\sqrt{1.5}}\frac{x^3}{\sqrt{2-x^2}}\,dx-\int_1^{\sqrt{1.5}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2-x^2}}\,dx $$
The first integral can be done with the substitution you suggest since $x^3\,dx=x^2\cdot x\,dx$ and $x\,dx=-t\,dt$. For the second one, you can use that
$$\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}\,dx=\sin^{-1}\left(\frac xa\right)+C\quad(a>0)  $$ so
$$\int_1^{\sqrt{1.5}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2-x^2}}\,dx=\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\Bigg|_1^{\sqrt{1.5}} $$

Comment: @jacky I didn't say you can't. I only said it doesn't lead to anything simpler so what's the point of doing it?

Answer (score 0):

You can just view the integrals geometrically as the area under the circle $x^2 + y^2 = 2$ between $x = 1$ and $x = \sqrt{2}$, and between $x = \sqrt{2}$ and $x = \sqrt{ 3 \over 2}$ respectively. The line $x = 1$ corresponds to $\theta = {\pi \over 4}$ and the line $x = \sqrt{ 3 \over 2}$ corresponds to $\theta = {\pi \over 6}$ so both areas can be computed using elementary geometry.